# Finding main diagonal matrix using pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm new to c++,
I'm trying to find main diagonal matrix using pointer array like

```
int * ProblemSolution :: solution(int *A,int N)
{
    //write your code here
    for (int m=0;m<N;m++){
        for (int x=0;x<N;x++){
            if(m=x)
                cout<<*(*(A+m)+x)<<",";
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

but i'm getting some kind of error:
[image]

can anyone help me?

Comment: there is no multidimensional-array in your code. `A` is just a pointer to an `int`. Use `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (<- not the most efficient) for dynamically sized arrays / 2d arrays if you can

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems

```
if(m=x)
```

is an assignment, you probably want,
    if(m==x)

Square bracket syntax is a lot clearer than pointer arithmetic,

```
A[m]
```

instead of,

```
*(A+m)
```

Also `*(A+m)` is an integer, so `*(A+m)+x` is also an integer which you can't dereference.

Your index should be something like:
A[m*N+x]

Answer (score 1):

- `A` is an `int*`
- `A+m` is also an `int*`
- `*(A+m)` is an `int`
- `(*(A+m) + x)` is also an `int`

Instead of `cout<<*(*(A+m)+x)<<",";` you could write `int tmp = (*(A+m)+x); cout << *tmp << ",";`.

You are trying to derefence a pointer.

---

To make things easier you should rather use appropriate types (e.g. `std::array`, `std::vector`) instead of using raw-pointers.

Comment: I would have to advice some matrix math library. those standard C++ components aren't well suited for typical use pattern required for such, and rolling own library if educationally very effective, is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Thanks @SimonKraemer for sharing your answer , it is working.

Answer (score 1):

`*(*(A+m) + x)` is an `int`,So try to store it in some variable then print it. Also you are mixing up 2D matrix(pointer to pointer) with 1D array(pointer).
try to do like-

```
*(A+m)=A[m] ,

*(*(A+m)+x) =A[m][x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up 2D matrix represented by pointer to pointer and  1D array represented by pointer, your case is the latter.

`*(*(A+m)+x)`  is legal only if A is a pointer to array decayed to a pointer to pointer, instead it should be `*(A + N*m +x)`